# Using generic for custom type

Tags: java, generics

I am working with some methods that write every type in a custom way. These are the signatures:

```
public void write(Boolean value);
public void write(Byte value);
...
public void write(Integer value);
public void write(Long value);
```

As the signatures are the same but changing the type, I have been thinking on using generics and a method that receives an unknown type and uses the correct method. Something similar to this:

```
public <T> void doWrite(T data) {
    write(data);
}
```

In this case the compiler gives me this error:

```
The method write(Boolean) in the type Writer is not applicable for the arguments (T).
```

Any hint on how could I do it ?

Comment: You need to specify the <T> while defining the class itself.

Comment: If you want to use generics you have to rewrite the code of your `write(s)` inside `doWrite` but I think is not a good idea doing something like `if(data instanceof Boolean)` and so on. So If you have yet different methods doing differnt things, why you need generics?

Answer (score 0):

As a rule of thumb, you should consider using generics when your code gets a lot of type querying (casts, instanceof). The purpose is to eliminate this casting. 
Your case seems not to be of this kind. On the contrary you will introduce this type querying by refactoring your code the way you ask, so I don't think it is apropriate

Comment: Ok, I understand but it's a pity, because the code I had would be the same in different methods because the just only the signature changes given the type.

Comment: Then why you wrote that "..and a method that receives an unknown type and uses the correct method". This implies that there is different code that handles each type accordingly. If the code is the same then you can safely go with the generic method and get rid of the others.

Comment: There is a reason, those write are really encapsulated in a different class(lets say **class A**), hidden to the consumer of the outer class (lets say **class B**).

**doWrite** is implemented in the **class B** and the idea is it to be a wrapper to the **class A** where custom code is written to handle each type, so the code in **doWrite** is the same for every type.